# Facebook SDK API IOS Error when posting to user's wall

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook, api, sdk

I am getting the following error when trying to post to the user's Facebook wall and I can't seem to find the source. Anyone have some insight on this issue?

```
2012-08-29 22:14:38.490 CanP[405:707] Error: HTTP status code: 400
2012-08-29 22:14:38.494 CanP[405:707] FBSDKLog: Response <#1111> <Error>:
The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)
```

The method that is run that should post the message to the facebook wall is as follows:

```
[FBSettings setLoggingBehavior:[NSSet setWithObjects:
                                FBLoggingBehaviorFBRequests,
                                nil]];
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:[facebook accessToken] forKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
[defaults setObject:[facebook expirationDate] forKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
[defaults synchronize];

NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               @"My test app", @"name",
                               @"http://www.google.com", @"link",
                               @"FBTestApp app for iPhone!", @"caption",
                               @"This is a description of my app", @"description",
                               @"Hello!\n\nThis is a test message\nfrom my test iPhone app!", @"message",
                               nil];

// Publish.
// This is the most important method that you call. It does the actual job, the message posting.
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/feed" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

Comment: I followed the [same tutorial](http://gabriel-tips.blogspot.nl/2011/10/how-to-post-on-facebook-wall-through.html) and I have the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you use the new SDK 3.1 methods for posting.

```
[FBRequestConnection
 startWithGraphPath:@"me/feed"
 parameters:params
 HTTPMethod:@"POST"
 completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                     id result,
                     NSError *error) {
     if (error) {
         /* Handle error */
     } else {
         /* Handle success */
     }
 }];
```

For a step by step tutorial, see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/publish-to-feed-ios-sdk/

Also make sure you ask for publish_action permissions first to make sure you can post to the wall.

If you still run into issues, place a breakpoint at the error line and take a look at the error variable then drill down to a dictionary named userInfo that should contain a much more readable error message.

Comment: Thank you so much. The userInfo dictionary is really the key to solving these problems.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by C Abernathy, you should "place a breakpoint at the error line and take a look at the error variable then drill down to a dictionary named userInfo that should contain a much more readable error message."

For those of us testing a new Facebook integration, **the most common problem** is likely to be shown in the `error.userInfo` `"com.facebook.sdk.ParsedJSONResponseKey"`:

```
message = "(#506) Duplicate status message";
```

Vary the text you use to test your Facebook integration, and you may find that your code is working just fine!

Comment: The userInfo is gold, thank you. At least you know why is not working rather than fixing it blindly.